# Language decidable or not?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability

I have just began with my course of complexity and computability and I need your experience to help me progress !!

Something is not clear for me:

[image: Exercise]

It is asked to determine if L1 is decidable or not, below the language is an answer given by a student. And I'm not agree with it...

The Rice theorem is given as follow :

[image: Rice Theorem]

I don't get why L1 is decidable since, for me, it looks like the Rice theorem could be immediately applied.

Did I understood very badly or am I right ? In the first case, why ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Elia

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score 3):

Rice's theorem only applies for nontrivial properties, which are properties which are not always true or not always false. Your property is trivial, since it's always true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !!

Is it trivial because L1 is actually equal to RE ?

Comment: The semantic property is trivial and so the language is recursive.

Comment: @EliaDratwa L1 can not be equal to RE: L1 is a language, RE is a _set_ of languages. The issue here is that $L1 = \{\langle M\rangle\ |\ M \mbox{is a TM}\}$, so to decide L1 we only need to understand whether a word is a description of some TM, which is a simple "parsing" problem, so to speak.